# Can't print swedish letters from a .rtf file

Tags: python, text-files

Im trying to read a text file (.rtf file) that contains swedish letters "åäö". But when im printing it out as a string it gives me ex. "'e4" instead of "ä". Is there a quick fix for this or do i need to write a bunch of additional code?

I'm pretty new to programming so i haven't understood the explanations when i googled the problem. Im guessing it has to do with the way python reads a rtf file but its weird cause in my schools tutorial they don't mention this as a problem.

Code:

```py
infil = open("/Users/fabianlarsson/Downloads/textFil.rtf", 'r')

print(infil.read())

infil.close()
```

Output:

```
Skriv ett program som l\'e4ser en textfil och producerar statistik. Du beh\'f6ver sj\'e4lv skapa en fil som programmet ska l\'e4sa. Programmet ska skriva ut det totala antalet ord och antalet olika ord. Programmet ska ocks\'e5 ge en lista p\'e5 de\'a0n\'a0vanligaste orden och de\'a0m\'a0ovanligaste orden. V\'e4rdena p\'e5\'a0m\'a0och\'a0n\'a0ska l\'e4sas in med\'a0\cf4 input\cf2 . Se minilektionen in- och utmatning som beskriver hur man l\'e4ser en fil.
```

How it should look:

```
Skriv ett program som läser en textfil och producerar statistik. Du behöver själv skapa en fil som programmet ska läsa. Programmet ska skriva ut det totala antalet ord och antalet olika ord. Programmet ska också ge en lista på de n vanligaste orden och de m ovanligaste orden. Värdena på m och n ska läsas in med input. Se minilektionen in- och utmatning som beskriver hur man läser en fil.
```

Comment: Please include a [mcve] in your question, as well as example input and output of your code.

Comment: How do you really know what's in the .rtf file? Have you looked at it with hex/binary viewer/editor?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk I haven't looked at it like that but what i have done is just created a rtf file on my mac and straight up typed into it with my keyboard so it's just the standard letters.

Comment: So you used TextEdit on the Mac?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Yes

Comment: Okay so i fixed it by simply changing the file to a txt file then copying in the text i want to use in it. I guess python just doesnt like rtf files.

Comment: Saving it as a text file is correct as long as TextEdit is using UTF-8 encoding for saving text files. RTF files use their own non-standard encoding of non-ASCII characters, so you'd have to do more processing of RTF file input if you want to properly decode them to characters.

Comment: Are you using python 2 or python 3? They handle unicode differently